# BigQuery StandardSQL: Last 7 Days using _TABLE_SUFFIX

Tags: google-bigquery

**Question:** I want to pull data from multiple Google Analytics sessions tables using _TABLE_SUFFIX, but I want to set the suffix parameters to between "seven days ago" and "one day ago" (i.e. pulling data for the last 7 days)

The current syntax (that doesn't work):

```
#StandardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  SUM (totals.visits) AS visits
FROM
  `projectname.123456789.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  'DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)' AND 
  'DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)'
GROUP BY 
   date
ORDER BY 
   date ASC
```

Which gives me the message "**Valid:** This query will process 0 B when run." To my eyes, there is no error in the syntax, but BigQuery is unable ot read my date functions and thus unable to suffix them to the ga_sessions_* wildcard

**Inspiration:**

BigQuery Cookbook has an example for legacySQL that I have been basing this on: (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#7days)

```
#LegacySQL
SELECT
  date,
  SUM (totals.visits) AS visits
FROM 
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([73156703.ga_sessions_], 
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), 
  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date ASC
```

**Things I've tried:** (that doesn't work)

Using DATE_SUB instead of DATE_ADD and using CURRENT_DATE instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
WHERE
   _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
   'DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)' AND 
   'DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'
```

Resulting in "**Valid:** This query will process 0 B when run."

Using DATE_FORMAT around DATE_SUB and CURRENT_DATE in order to get the dates without dashes:

```
WHERE
   _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
   'FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))' AND 
   'FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))'
```

Resulting in "**Valid:** This query will process 0 B when run."

Tried skippingt he hyphens '' around the DATE_SUB clause

```
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Resulting in the following error message "**Error:** No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: STRING, DATE, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY)"

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Elliott's answer is correct, but if you want to get the most performance out of BigQuery for such kind of query, instead of converting `_TABLESUFFIX` to `DATE`, you should convert `CURRENT_DATE` expressions to strings:

```
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: Thank you! Credit where credit is due to Elliot, but performance is also an imporant angle, especially while processing large volumes of data. Changing to the acceoted answer. (for new readers, also see my comment on Elliott Brossards answer regarding a small edit to the wildcard)

Comment: I think the date format needs to be "%Y%m%d" as the capitol Y outputs the 4 digit year while the lowercase is the 2 digit year

Comment: @Elliott Brossard's answer is the correct answer. I tried this with my own but didn't return result. But the Elliot's answer works for me.

Comment: not sure this is correct - when I hard code the date range - I seem to get different data using ``` WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180708" and "20180715
)```

Comment: Was using the same until now but now it is showing  0 B and no results and now  works when dates are hardcoded

Answer (score 13):

You were almost there with your last attempt. You need to convert your string to a date in order to use it in the comparison:

```
WHERE
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion resulted in another error, but worked after some slight editing to the wildcard. (explanation for new readers:
parse_date could not handle _intradate_ datasets, so the new wildcard should be  `projectname.123456789.ga_sessions_20*` and the parse date should be PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) with a non-capital y to get 2-digit year instead of 4-digit year.)

Comment: This approach took less than half of the time of the accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works for anyone just looking to segment out the last week of data in big query. Works for any data set as long as you have a timestamp!

```
where TIMESTAMPFIELD >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to include today's data, use the `intraday` table:

**Google Analytics:** ([docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en))

```
SELECT *
FROM `myproject.xxxxxxx.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
  FORMAT_DATE("intraday_%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())
```

**Google Analytics for Firebase:** ([docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en))

```
SELECT *
FROM `myproject.analytics_xxxxxxx.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND
  FORMAT_DATE("intraday_%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())
```