# Rolling 7 days in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've recently migrated my code from Legacy SQL and need a replacement for TABLE_DATE_RANGE, how can this be achieved using standard SQL? My data is GA tables imported into BigQuery in the YYYYMMDD format.

I have read through the migration documentation but I don't understand how I can apply a dynamic date range (for example last 7 days) using _TABLE_SUFFIX. I understand how I could use this to pull date for a particular month, but not for a rolling range. Is this possible?

Comment: A `WHERE` clause would be one thing to try.

Comment: As written, it's hard to give a meaningful answer to your question. Take a look at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) and other SO `google-bigquery` posts about `_TABLE_SUFFIX` and then see if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I have read through he documentation but i can't see how I can apply a dynamic date range (for example last 7 days) using _TABLE_SUFFIX. I understand how i could use this to pull date for a particular month, but not for a rolling range. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question on this post:
[BigQuery StandardSQL: Last 7 Days using _TABLE_SUFFIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770893/bigquery-standardsql-last-7-days-using-table-suffix)

I added in:

```
WHERE
  PARSE_DATE('%y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) BETWEEN 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

And updated my wildcard to `.ga_sessions_20*` instead of `.ga_sessions_*`

Thanks everyone for your help.